# Version control in iOS for an update

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

I recently released an app to the app store, and it works pretty well, but there were a few errors that I need to fix in an update. Namely, sometimes the score doesn't save correctly, and users cannot listen to their own music in the app. I never used version/source control when building the project, and I never used github.

So, I'm wondering if I should save a copy of the current version before updating it, or if the archive (created when I submitted the project to iTunes connect) is a suitable copy of the project (or is the archive in binary?)?

If the archive does not work as a copy of the code I can revert to (because it is in binary), are there any recommendations on how to save this working version of the app? Also, should I change the plist version before making edits?

Thanks. If this question is unclear just comment and I will try to explain better.

Comment: As you didn't create a version control repository I would copy paste a copy of your directory in a safe place just in case. Then I would add my folder to a version control (SVN, GIT) repository and start using version control it will be beneficial in long term for your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **best** answer is simple: use a dedicated software version control system.

**Use Git.**

[Git documentation and getting started help.](http://git-scm.com/)

It's very easy to get started, even if you already have a ton of code.

```
$ cd ~/path/to/project
$ git init
$ git add -A 
$ git commit -m "This is the version that is currently on the store"
```

Done.

Alternatives:

- Create a copy of your Xcode project folder.
- An Xcode archive is not good enough because you may need to revert back your code.

Comment: Thank you! This question is old, but I realized i never marked it as a correct answer.